# Are the packets meant to drop after IP spoof?

Tags: ip, arp, spoofing

I was just experimenting ARP IP spoofing with a few virtual machines at home and did something like this.

VM1 IP - 192.168.132.1
VM2 IP - 192.168.132.2
VM3 IP - 192.168.132.3
VM4 IP - 192.168.132.4

Basically from `VM1 (192.168.132.1)` I pinged `VM2 (192.168.132.2)` 6 times and the packets all went fine. Then on `VM3 (192.168.132.3)`, I spoofed the IP of `VM2(192.168.132.2)`. After that from `VM1 (192.168.132.1)` I pinged VM2 `(192.168.132.2)` again - but then this time, all the packets dropped and nothing went through to `VM2 (192.168.132.2)`.

Is this normal? My intention was to fool `VM1 (192.168.132.1)` into believing that I, `VM3(192.168.132.3)` was in fact `VM2(192.168.132.2)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want some diagnostic information about what is happening here. Run `tcpdump` on VM1, and look at the order it received ARP replies and the MAC address that is used in the ICMP Ping Request.

In a seperate terminal from your ping terminal, run these commands. We flush the ARP cache to force a fresh ARP request with our ping, then we start tcpdump up so that it prints MAC addresses in the packet capture and it excludes our own ssh session.

```
sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all
sudo tcpdump -ne -s 1500 port not 22
```

Does that explain your issue?